# aws-encryption-cli encryption adds newline character

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-cli

I'm encrypting some values in our production environment EC2 instance and inserting them directly to the database, bypassing API (I won't get into it but that how it needs to be done). I'm able to encrypt and decrypt values successfully, but it seems that when doing so from the command line, it adds a newline character at the end:

`echo "VA" | /usr/local/bin/aws-encryption-cli --encrypt \ --encode \ --input - \ --wrapping-keys key=XXX \ --metadata-output ~/metadata \ --commitment-policy require-encrypt-require-decrypt \ --output -`

I tried specifying input/output files but same effect. Server side is able to decrypt data but throwing an application level error because it detect the value (state abbreviation) contains more than two characters.

I tried encrypting the values in different ways on the command line but to no avail. Existing database values were successfully decrypted and do not contain any newline character.

Comment: **It's the `echo` command** that adds a newline. On _some_ shells or systems `echo -n "VA"` suppresses this, but you don't say which you are using. [The portable Unix (POSIX) solution is `printf %s "VA"`.'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) (On Windows it's kludgier.)

Comment: I also used input files (not using the echo command) and that resulted in the same thing. I will give it a try again, though, just in case I got confused somehow. I'll post again if this was indeed the case.

Comment: Yep! That was it! thanks for the -n thingy. I was 100% I also tried input/output files to make sure it wasn't something with echo, and actually had another pair of eyes other than myself. We must have missed something or done something wrong. Thanks!